# Sanitise specific HTML attribute values against XSS

Tags: php, xss, html

We want to implement a "safe mode" in [a Markdown parser called Parsedown](http://parsedown.org). We have a `MarkupEscaped` option that disables HTML input, but this is not enough. In order to be safe, the parser needs to sanitise user generated attribute values.

These are the:

- `href` and `title` attributes of `a` tags.
- `src` and `title` attributes of `img` tags.

How should we process these values to make them safe for the attributes that they belong to?

Comment: Be sure to canonicalize the input before filtering.  Some characters are representable by more than one Unicode sequence.  There is more info here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode

Comment: _"In order to be safe, the parser needs to sanitise user generated attribute values."_ Also, would need to sanitise the following: `[xss](http://"onmouseover="alert(1))`.

Comment: _"We want to implement a "safe mode"_ This feature is still to be implemented or the team decided to leave this task to some 3rd party sanitizer (ex: HTML Purifier) ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to escape all quote variations (single and double) and restrict the URL in the `href` and `src` attribute to an XSS-safe scheme like `http:` or `https:` (as opposed to `javascript:`, `data:` or whatever).

Also consider running the parser output through [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to keep it in a sandbox environment. This will catch weaknesses of your own implementation in case you've overlooked something (which can always happen).

Last but not least, custom HTML markup should always be backed up with [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP). But this may be beyond the scope of your project.